# upgrade or compile phonon from sources

Tags: kde

I am trying to compile KDE from sources and I get this error when trying to make kdelibs:

`Could NOT find Phonon: Found version "4.3.1", but required is at least
  "4.3.80"`

I am running Kubuntu karmic ... and I have the latest phonon dev files. How can I upgrade it to the version that kdelibs needs?

Answer (score 0):

Get phonon from Gitorious (http://gitorious.org/phonon), and compile it and install the same way you'd do with other KDE SC modules.

Mind that if you don't install it with the same prefix as the system's is, you'll have to tinker with cmake to tell it where the new phonon is.

p.s. It would be a good thing first to uninstall the old libphonon and install the new one by checkinstall so that the apt system knows that phonon is installed